# How can I create the following layout in xml to use as a background for my android activities?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'd like to create a gradient with 3 rings overlaid on it and use this as a background for all screens in my android app, either using the android:background property in xml or the SetBackgroundResource method depending on how each activity is being created.

Example background layout :

[image: Gradient overlaid with rings]

I have the following xml in my drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

            <gradient
                android:startColor="#C0F57C9B"
                android:endColor="#C0C70F3F"
                android:angle="225" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:innerRadius="90dp"
            android:thickness="8dp"
            android:useLevel="false">

            <solid android:color="#24f45995" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:innerRadius="60dp"
            android:thickness="10dp"
            android:useLevel="false">

            <solid
                android:color="#24f45995" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:innerRadius="40dp"
            android:thickness="6dp"
            android:useLevel="false">

            <solid
                android:color="#24f45995" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

The problem I have is how to position the rings.
Is a layer-list the right way to go or should I be using some other method?

Grateful for any advice.

Comment: you can use this image as your background..why you want to create this..

Comment: Why don't you use photoshop to create such image? And then you can use it for background.

Comment: I could use an image but this seemed a little wasteful of resources.

Comment: @Aniruddha in search of perfection, we always try to find some ways to spare resources. XML drawables are quite inexpensive, and you don't have to provide them in a bunch of resolutions.

Comment: @LeeBee To position your circles, try playing with their padding / margin attibutes

Comment: good suggestion and I did try it, but margin has no effect and padding affects the rest of your layout pushing other elements off screen etc.

Comment: @LeeBee how about doing it programatically (in java, not xml) ? U will have more control to render it on different screen dimension ( Ratio, Size, Orientation etc ).

Comment: @LeeBee If you insist want to use xml, perhaps you can try the android:top, android:left, android:bottom, android:right attribute in <item>